# npm run serve not running the project in react js with webpack environment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack, serve

I'm trying to route some component in `react` js. So I install `npm` install `serve --save-dev`. After I run this comment "

> npm run serve

I'm getting some errors.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOWU4.jpg]

Here my package file.

```
{
  "name": "routing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "routing test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack -d --watch",
    "build": "webpack",
    "serve" : "serve ./public"
  },
  "author": "VJ",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.23.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
    "serve": "^5.0.2",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
    "react-router": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here my web packs file

```
    var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    Loaders: [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile from ES6 to ES5 first.
For reference, user should add `babel-preset-es2015` package as you already did.

```
npm install babel-preset-es2015
```

Then, create a .babelrc with the following:

```
{ 
   "presets": 
     [
       "es2015",
       ...
     ]
}
```

**Note:** By default, latest version of node supports ES6 Destruction. So, updating node version may help with your issue.

Comment: Even .babelrc file?

Comment: You check my package file, in the above attached!

Comment: Yeah I have  a .babelrc file.

Comment: Ok please mention your babelrc configuration

Comment: {
  "presets" : ["es2015", "react"]
}

Comment: Ok check your node version. `node --version`

Answer (score 0):

You're running an old Node.js version that doesn't support [Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

The package `serve` uses that feature, so you need at least Node.js version 6, which is the current LTS. It even says it in its [README](https://github.com/zeit/serve#usage) and it's also specified in the [package.json](https://github.com/zeit/serve/blob/39131654fecadc8905f0079e8d65f18001e01488/package.json#L21).

The easiest and the best solution is to upgrade Node.js. Alternatively you could transpile the module with babel, but that's rather inconvenient.

Comment: I check my node version "node -v" in my node cmd. My version is v4.3.2. I think this is latest version.

Comment: This is not the latest version. Current LTS is `v6.10.0` and current latest is `v7.7.2`. You're 2 to 3 major versions behind. See [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) and the [LTS schedule](https://github.com/nodejs/LTS#lts-schedule). Node 4 is about to enter maintenance, where only critical security patches are applied.